# Exception when a path to a file is null (when you cancel OpenFiledDalog)

Tags: c#, exception, openfiledialog

This is the code:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("Error."); }

//later on..
        DataTable lertableEC0 = new DataTable();
        lertableEC0.ReadXml(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

and right here in the end comes the error, everything works fine, the xml import, etc only if i cancel in the open dialog i get the exception, any hint?

(there ir a similar question but the answer is still very confusing for me

```
  return null;
```

didnt work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
  {
        string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        DataTable lertableEC0 = new DataTable();
        lertableEC0.ReadXml(openFileDialog1.FileName);       
  }
 else { 
       MessageBox.Show("Error.");
  }
```

Since filename is not set if Cancel button is clicked , empty string is passed to `ReadXml()` function which throws exception . So you have to move the function inside OK click condition

Comment: It was exactly that, moving all the file processing inside the test result solved it, thank you very much @m-hasan

Answer (score 1):

When you Cancel the dialog, [`FileDialog.FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `""` (the empty string) *because nothing was selected*.

To handle this - e.g. don't do anything if no files were selected - make sure to only use FileName in the "*if* OK dialog result" logic.

```
DataTable lertableEC0 = new DataTable();
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
    // -> openFileDialog1.FileName is not empy here
    lertableEC0.ReadXml(openFileDialog1.FileName);
} else {
    // -> openFileDialog1.FileName is empty here
    MessageBox.Show("Error.");
}
// -> openFileDialog1.FileName may or may not be empty here
```